# Can't access my kubernetes pod in browser using ingress and can't connect it to backend

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

This is the continuation of my previous problem. I have a project, I need to put it in kubernetes so it works properly. It has a database container, a backend container (which uses express) and a frontend container (react). Connection between backend and my database works fine, but frontend can't connect to backend. I tried using ingress, but I wasn't able to figure it out how to use it to make frontend accessible from the browser or to make frontend connect to backend. Currently the only way I can do it is using links provided by command `minikube service <frontend-service for connecting to it from browser and backend-service to input into frontend.yaml for it to connect to it>`. That approach is terrible, but it works. How do I make it so I don't need to use that command? I also tried nodeports on the way there, but it didn't work.
frontend.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: cloud-frontend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
          env:
            - name: REACT_APP_API_URL
              value: "http://backend-service:5001"
            - name: PORT
              value: "3001"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
      nodePort: 30001
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: finelist1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 3001
```

Don't mind the nodePort thing, I tried other types too, it didn't work.
backend.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: cloud-backend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "5001"
            - name: DBLINK
              value: "mongodb://database-service:27017/TODO"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
  type: ClusterIP
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.49.2
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: backend-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: backend-ingress-class
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-service
                port:
                  number: 5001
```

Again, this approach doesn't work unless I do the `minikube service` command. The app works perfectly fine in that case and can be accessed from the browser using the link provided by that command. And yes, I did add finelist1.com to the hosts config in Windows.

Comment: How does your frontend try to connect to the backend? The ingress has to somehow explain how the separation is done, you can’t just have two things with same path prefix and ingress controller would magically guess what to do. Either need a prefix, different hostname, priorities…

Comment: It connects using a link in an ENV variable.